# Can i use CLUTO package from C#?

Tags: c#, cluster-analysis, cluto

I am wondering whether there are some C#-specific builds of CLUTO package for using its APIs directly from C# project.

As i understand, you need to include ".h" file, provided with the package, to make it work.
That's a problem.

**Edit**: adding reference to Cluto: http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/views/cluto